# do.call forces argument evaluation before rlang's tidy evaluation

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang, do.call, tidyeval

I'm trying to use quosures to store references to objects I'm operating on. `do.call` breaks the idea, evaluating the arguments early, so the resulting `quosure` stores a new copy of object evaluated in `empty_env()`, instead of an actual call to object.

`rlang::exec()` gives same results, since it relies on `do.call`. `rlang::eval_tidy(call2(..))` approach seems to be a solution, as well as based on it `rlang::invoke()`.

The questions are:

What's the desired way in R to store the reference to an object/object call, instead of storing it explicitly in a list.

Is it ok to mix `do.call` and `rlang`, since it leads to unnecessary computation and copying?

Why `invoke` is soft-deprecated, while better fitting the rlang's philosophy, than `exec`?

```r
require(rlang)
#> Loading required package: rlang

quoting_fun <- function(x) {
  x_enq <- enquo(x) # enquote
  x + length(x) # do something
  x_enq
}

obj <- 1:10L

quoting_fun(obj) # ok
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^obj
#> env:  global
do.call(quoting_fun, list(obj)) # not ok
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^<int: 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, ...>
#> env:  empty


exec(quoting_fun, obj)
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^<int: 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, ...>
#> env:  empty

rlang::invoke(quoting_fun, list(obj))
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^1
#> env:  000000001C8DDFD8
eval_tidy(call2(quoting_fun, quo(obj)))
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^obj
#> env:  global
```

Created on 2019-02-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Multipart questions are considered too broad. Focus on one issue at a time. That way you canshow what searching you have done and why earlier answers were insufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Quote the argument:

```
do.call(quoting_fun, list(quote(obj)))
#<quosure>
#expr: ^obj
#env:  global
```

The evaluation happens in `list` and not in `do.call`.

Comment: No, since a `quosure`, not `int`, will be passed to `quoting_fun()`. I'm already quoting an argument that is passed to `call2()`, but this works since it already uses `list2()` to quote the arguments.